# Running Groovy Script from R

Tags: r, groovy

I have groovy script file (.groovy). I want to execute this groovy script file in R. Please note the input for groovy file has 3 different variables and I created all 3 variables in the form of list

Answer (score 0):

```
# This installs the package on your machine to read the groovy file
install.packages("readr") 

variables <- list ()
variables["first"] = "First"
variables["second"]  = "Second"
variables["third" = "Third"


library(readr)
myscript <- read_file("path/to/groovycode.groovy")


result <- Execute (groovyScript=myscript, variables=variables)
result
```

I didn't test the code, but can be a good start if you can fix any issues when trying to run it.